# JavaScript Search() not finding target

Tags: javascript

Does anyone see why the first three searches in the jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/tJ9uQ/  return -1?

Thanks

```
var gotoTarget = "http://register.php?from=";

var off1 = gotoTarget.search('register.php?from=');
    console.log ("off1="+off1);
    off2 = gotoTarget.search('register.php\?from=');
    console.log ("off2="+off2);
    off3 = gotoTarget.search('register.phpfrom=');
    console.log ("off3="+off3);
    off4 = gotoTarget.search('register.php');
    console.log ("off4="+off4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter passed to `.search()` is a regular expression. If a regular expression is not passed, what is passed is implicitly converted to a regular expression.

Per the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search):

> `str.search(regexp)`
>
> #### Parameters
>
> A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).

You need to escape the question mark, as the question mark is a valid regex character.

```
var off1 = gotoTarget.search('register\\.php\\?from=');
console.log(off1); // returns 7
```

In your examples above, the first one is not escaped at all, the second is incorrectly escaped and third is missing the `?` so no match will be found.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/tJ9uQ/2/)

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I took care of that case in off2 but I guess I need to escape the escape to get it into search().  In this new light, it looks like the "." is also a problem.  If I really want to look for "." and not any single char I need \\.